# Can you replace a unicode character in XSLT?

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to replace a Register trademark symbol with an empty string.

I've tried:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace( $myVariable, '&#9415;' ,'')"/>
```

But that didn't replace the Registered trademark symbol. Is there a way to replace it?

Comment: "Didn't work" is not a good description of a problem. See: [mcve].

Comment: @michael.hor257k Didn't work as in 'didn't replace.' Thought that was very clear.

Comment: No, it is not clear at all. What exactly is in your variable? Was there an error? What version of XSLT does your processor support? And so on. Please post a **reproducible** example.

Comment: The answer to your headline question is "yes, you can". The answer to the implied question "why isn't this code working" is "we don't know, you haven't given us enough information to go on".

Comment: Example of the "yes, you can" @MichaelKay mentioned: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nb9PtCZ

Comment: @DanielHaley, Thank you for providing me with that example. The reason why my question was worded the way it was, is because I thought my syntax wasn't correct. But I can see that it was correct from you example. Turned out the client had copied and pasted it from somewhere (my guess is their symbol doesn't have the same unicode). See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEJbVqS for a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that I was using the xsl:replace() function correctly. The client was using the symbol with the following unicode 174.

Answer (score 2):

Your client is right and you are wrong. They are using the REGISTERED SIGN character (`&#174;`). Your character (`&#9415;`) is actually CIRCLED LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R.

Comment: Yes. Just figured out this. Thank you! The reason why I asked this question in the first place because I was thinking that I wasn't using the replace function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to use this symbol anymore from your variable, try to use the translate() function:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate($myVariable, '&#9415;', '')"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, Rally! turned out the client had copied and pasted the symbol from somewhere. See xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEJbVqS for a reference.